# Recursive Unzipping with 7z.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, unzip, 7zip

I stumbled across the below line as a means of extracting every .zip file in every subfolder.

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %a in (`DIR /s /b *.zip`) do 7z.exe e %a
```

I've tried this on a WinXP cmd.exe prompt and I get the error:

```
"a was unexpected at this time."
```

Can somebody please tell me whats wrong with the above line. Is this a 7z.exe error or is there something wrong with the batch script syntax. I did cut and paste this into a .bat file.

Cheers

Comment: Did you try using `%%a`?

Comment: This is the answer.. now you'd better click on "Answer Question" so I can accept your answer and give you some points. :-) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to change **%a** with **%%a**:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%a in (`DIR /s /b *.zip`) do 7z.exe e %%a
```

Comment: Can someone explain what usebackq means and where it comes from?

Comment: @Pat: it's used to tell the parsing engine to use backquotes to identify command or filenames to process. Look at `DIR /s /b *.zip`

Answer (score 13):

Building on @PA.'s answer (remember to remove the `@echo` when you've verified that the output is what you want), if you want to preserve the directory structure inside the zip file, use the `x` command instead of `e`:

```
FOR /R %a IN (*.zip) DO @echo 7z x "%a"
```

And if you want to extract the files into a folder with the same name as their respective zip file, use the `-o` switch and the `%~n` filename extractor prefix:

```
FOR /R %a IN (*.zip) DO @echo 7z x "%a" -o"%~na"
```

Finally, if you want to do all of the above and overwrite any existing files, use the `-aoa` switch:

```
FOR /R %a IN (*.zip) DO @echo 7z x "%a" -o"%~na" -aoa
```

### Helpful resources

- http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples

### Batch file

Here it is, all condensed. The following is a batch script that will work for all zip files in the current folder (assuming 7zip is installed). It defaults to `echo`ing what commands *would run* and only runs when you pass in `/y` (as in, yes, please do the unzipping now).

```
:: To actually include the path expansion character (tilde), I had to give valid numbers; see http://ss64.com/nt/rem.html for bug reference. Also, try call /? for more info.
@REM The %~n0 extracts the name sans extension to use as output folder. If you need full paths, use "%~dpn0". The -y forces overwriting by saying yes to everything. Or use -aoa to overwrite.
@REM Using `x` instead of `e` maintains dir structure (usually what we want)

@FOR /R %%a IN (*.zip) DO @(
    @if [%1] EQU [/y] (
        @7z x "%%a" -o"%%~dpna" -aoa
    ) else (
        @echo 7z x "%%a" -o"%%~dpna" -aoa
    )
)

@echo USAGE: Use /y to actually do the extraction
```

Answer (score 9):

read `HELP FOR` and then try the following in a command prompt...

```
FOR /R %a IN (*.zip) DO @ECHO 7z e "%a"
```

note that we have enclosed %a in "

Once you have checked the validity of the output, remove the ECHO. I would suggest to move the command into a BAT file. In that case, change %a to %%a

```
@echo off
FOR /R %%a IN (*.zip) DO (
  7z e "%%a"
)
```

Comment: The second suggestion PA is also very cool thanks - I needed the double quotes that you used.